# Symfony 3.4 - Inject variable from parameters.yml/config_test.yml into test case

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, phpunit, symfony-3.4

I have in my parameters.yml file

```
parameters:
    api_domain: api.domain.here
```

and in my config_test.yml

```
parameters:
    api_domain: api.localhost
```

I have a test case with

```
$this->client = static::createClient(
    [],
    [
        'HTTP_HOST' => 'api.localhost'
    ]
);
```

and I need to replace 'api.localhost' with the parameter api_domain based off of the environment

Any ideas how how I can do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried accessing the container and reading the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need that?

I mean it doesn't matter the host it should work right, so I don't know what you wanna test with it.

BUT you could do:

```
$this->client = static::createClient(
    [],
    [
        'HTTP_HOST' => static::$kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('api_domain')
    ]
);
```